How to simplify $\frac{4x(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^2}{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^4-1} $ to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$?
This question is from the second unit of Skanaviy math book. Here is the expression:
$$\frac{4x(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^2}{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^4-1} $$
First I tried to expand the denominator using $(a-b)(a+b)$ but at the end I am only being able to factor $4x$ from the denominator. I got this result: $(2x^2-2x\sqrt{x^2-1}-2)(2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2-1})$ and I factored out $4x$. But I don't know what to do next, I am stuck here. Then I tried to expand the numerator using the $a^2+2ab+b^2$, but I still couldn't simplify it as in the answer at the back of the book.
The answer was like this: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$.
Why was this question closed? Is it because this question already got its answer? I am new to this platform so I am learning the rules of posting questions here. If I broke some rule, can you tell me what was the mistake?

Dont expand the denominator, factor it. It's difference of two squares: $c^4 - 1 = (c^2-1)(c^2+ 1)$.

I got this result:  $(2x^2-2x\sqrt{x^2-1}-2)(2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2-1})$ and I factored out 4x. But I don't know what to do next, I am stuck here.

Letting $y=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$ helps. Note that $x=\frac{y^2+1}{2y}$.

Hint: Try using substitution $x=\cosh(t)$

@QuýNhân, can you explain what is cosh(t) because i don't know it yet

@Inf, I understood that we can let $y=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$ but i couldn't quite understand the second equality.

I don't understand why your question was closed, since you've shown your attempt. It has now 3 reopen votes, you can edit the question adding more context/show more steps and it'll be probably reopened

@SineoftheTime, thanks for the tip. You are helping me a lot, I appreciate it. I read the guidelines for a good question and I assume I failed this point: "Pare question to its basics". I think in the initial question I just asked the question without going into details of my approach.
By the way, what does it mean that this question is closed and no longer accepts answers while I already got my answer for this question?

No the question was not closed because you've got an answer; apparently it has not enough context; to improve it: "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc."

Carry on from where you're stuck:
\begin{align}\frac{4x(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^2}{(2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2-1}-2)(2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2-1})}&=\frac{4x(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^2}{2(x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-1}-1)2x(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}\\&=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-1}-1}  \end{align}
Now note that $x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-1}-1=(x^2-1)+x\sqrt{x^2-1}=\sqrt{x^2-1} (\sqrt{x^2-1}+x)$.
Can you conlude now?

Sine of  the Time, thanks much for the help. Looking at your answer, I am question myself, why I could not notice that $(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^2$ in the numerator can be reduced with $x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$ in the denominator. But now I get it, thanks much.

@JustInterestedInMath that happens, one have to be careful on choosing what to factor sometimes
